# Reactive R/Shiny Example Fails after Parameterizing One Variable

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have the following simple and working shiny-Rmarkdown document. It produces a slider and outputs a date below, which is adjusted based on the slider input.

````
---
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(rmarkdown); library(ggvis); library(shiny);

sliderInput("sliderDays", "Days forward from 1/1/2014: ", min=0, max=45, value=1, step=1)

graphDate = reactive({as.Date("2014-01-01") + input$sliderDays})
renderPrint(graphDate()) 
```
````

However, if I replace `graphDate = reactive({as.Date("2014-01-01") + input$sliderDays})` with

```
startDate <- as.Date("2014-04-01")
graphDate <- reactive({startDate + input$SliderDays})
```

then the output of `renderPrint(graphDate())` goes from

> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxDrQ.png) "2014-04-01"  [this changes on slider input, but is always a date]

to

> character(0)

I don't understand why the startDate would have to be created and used inside the graphDate reactive function, as opposed to defined right above it and referenced in the reactive function, for this to work.[image]

```
sessionInfo()
## R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
## Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
## Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
## 
## locale:
## [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
## [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
## [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
## [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
## [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] DT_0.0.52         shiny_0.12.0      knitr_1.10.5      ggvis_0.4.1.9000 
## [5] rmarkdown_0.6.2.2
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] Rcpp_0.11.6      digest_0.6.8     dplyr_0.4.1      assertthat_0.1  
##  [5] mime_0.3         R6_2.0.1         xtable_1.7-4     jsonlite_0.9.16 
##  [9] DBI_0.3.1        formatR_1.2      magrittr_1.5     evaluate_0.7    
## [13] stringi_0.4-1    rstudioapi_0.3.1 tools_3.2.0      stringr_1.0.0   
## [17] htmlwidgets_0.4  yaml_2.1.13      httpuv_1.3.2     parallel_3.2.0  
## [21] htmltools_0.2.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me. Did I understand the question right?

[image]

Version Info and Session Info:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Mike thanks a lot for the fast response. You understood the question correctly. That's very curious, I'm looking at a doc with the same code but different output. I'll attach the PDF of my rendered document to my answer.

Comment: Hey Mike, much appreciated (+1), though now I'm unfortunately less confident in getting to a solution as it seems like we're looking at the same code producing different output. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: boom fixed. wow I'm mildly horrified I posted a capitalization error on SO. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: I have done worse.  It is a nice little example frankly.

Comment: Hey you should ping me. Looks like I am doing work in your area (energy and smart buildings), would love to talk to a pro as I am completely green. mikewise1618 at  gmail